# WordPress - How to get nth post of the loop?

Tags: wordpress

I'm ordering posts by descending order of a custom field value, and I'd like to know if there is a way to find the nth post in the descending order.

Example, order is:

```
1st from top: id = 9
2nd from top: id = 5
3rd from top: id = 6
```

Now, I'm using `get_template_part()` to show posts.

I want to know if there is something as `get_template_part_of_post(3rd-from-top)`.

```
<div class="onethird">

                    <?php


                    $count_posts = wp_count_posts("ott_products", "");
                    $published_posts_orig = $count_posts->publish;
                    $published_posts = $published_posts_orig +  (3 - ($published_posts_orig % 3));


                    $i = 0;

                    if ( have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) :

                        echo $i . " " . $published_posts;
                        $i = $i + 3;
                        $query->the_post();

                        get_template_part( 'content', 'category' );

                        if ( $i % 3 === 2 ) :
                            if ( ($i - 2 == $published_posts) ) :
                                $i = 3;
                        endif; endif;

                        if ( $i % 3 === 1 ) :
                            if ( ($i - 1 == $published_posts) ) :
                                echo "</div><div class='onethird last'>";
                                $i = 2;
                        endif; endif;

                        if ( $i % 3 === 0 ) :
                            if ( ($i == $published_posts) ) :
                                echo "</div><div class='onethird'>";
                                $i = 1;
                        endif; endif; 


                    endwhile;

                    else :

                        get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );

                    endif;  

                    ?>


            </div>
```

This is what I'm using currently. This divides the posts into three columns.

The variable `i` turns what would have been from up to down in three columns, to left to right.

Previously, I had the posts being displayed like:

```
(Total 9 posts)
1  4  7
2  5  8
3  6  9
```

With it, I get the `i` to:

```
(Total n posts)
1  2  3
4  5  6
...
```

Now, the problem is that I can't get `i`th post to display. The posts *still* come in the first order.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/175399/141492

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get the `nth` post is to do something like this:

```
global $posts;

// This gets your nth level post object.
if( isset( $posts[ $nth_post ] ) )
    echo $posts[ $nth_post ]->post_title;
```

I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can first use total_posts = wp_count_posts() to count the number of posts.

You'll then have to run "the loop" and keep a counter for each post, and when that counter hits total_posts - N, perform your desired action:

PSEUDOCODE:

```
total_posts = wp_count_posts();
count = 0;
while(have_posts()) {
   count++;
   if (count = total_posts - N) {
       // ACTION       
   }
   the_post();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've edited the code above to explain why this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_part()` does exactly what it says, it gets a template that's located in your theme folder. The only arguments it accepts are the slug and the name (see [WordPress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part))

If I understand correctly, you'd like to get fetch the 3rd post every time? The simplest way would be to set up a counter and conditionals in your template file, likely `loop-something.php`.

```
$i = 0;

if ( have_posts()): 

while (have_posts()) : the_post();

  if ($i % 3 == 0):
    // Do something different, this is the first column.
    // I propose:
    $column = 1;

  elseif ($i % 3 == 1):
    // Do something different, this is the second column.
    $column = 2;

  elseif ($i % 3 == 2):
    // Do something different, this is the third column.
    $column = 3;
  endif;

  echo '<div class="column-'.$column.'">';
  // the post
  echo '</div>';

  $i++;

endwhile;

else:

  get_template_part( 'no-results', 'archive' );

endif;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, but with my current setup, this won't work. Edited the answer to explain why. I'd like something like `get_post(i);`.

Comment: edited my answer. I suggest not relying too much on the HTML to build columns, however. Use some CSS :)